# .Net Core build a solution

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

If you try to run from the command line in the top directory of a solution made with visual studio:

```
dotnet build
```

My solution is architectured like that:

```
MySolution.sln
   > src
       > MyProject1
           > project.json
       > MyProject2
           > project.json
   > test
       > MyProject.Test
           > project.json
```

it will fail with the following error:

```
Couldn't find 'project.json' in current directory
```

How could I build the solution without having to specify each project explicitely (and then without the related maintenance) ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### .NET Core 1.0 Preview (project.json)

You can use wildcards like that from the top directory (where lies the .sln).

- With the `project.json` in `SolutionDir/Src/ProjectName`:

  `dotnet build */**/project.json`
- If `project.json` in `SolutionDir/ProjectName`:

  `dotnet build **/project.json`

***Note: [It's recommended to migrate to new csproj project format to get support and new features.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/#migration-from-projectjson-to-csproj)***

### Since .NET Core 1.0 RTM

The solution is back for good.

```sh
  dotnet build solution.sln
```

In powershell, build all csproj file under the current directory.

```bsh
foreach ($csproj in $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse . -Filter *.csproj) )
{
    dotnet build $csproj.FullName
}
```

Comment: I had to modify the answer to get it working:

dotnet build **/project.json

Comment: U could use tool like flubu (fluent builder) to make things easier. More about on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890522/choice-for-build-tool-msbuild-nant-or-something-else/42513062#42513062

Answer (score 6):

If you arrive here looking for the command to build a SLN with `dotnet` CLI (version > 3.1), using only CLI args, it's below.

```
dotnet build <PATH>/<TO>/<SLN_FILE>.sln
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#arguments

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer, if you are publishing the project, use `dotnet publish src\MyProject1\` to publish all the files.

Publishing will include files defined to be included in project.json.

Answer (score 0):

With dotnet CLI 2.1, it could build the solution.
Here is my config:

```
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/SolutionName.sln",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
```