# Get svn revision and set it to assembly by Jenkins

Tags: svn, build, .net-assembly, revision

I build my first model in Jenkins,
I tried to get the svn revision by the variable *SVN_REVISION* but it does not work.

I need it to set it in my assemblyInfo files.

I made a search in google and got nothig.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use flubu that we wrote. Flubu is A C# library for building projects and executing deployment scripts using C# code.

More about flubu can be found here: [Choice for build tool: MSBuild, NANT or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890522/choice-for-build-tool-msbuild-nant-or-something-else/42513062#42513062)

For your particular case you'd have to Generate CommonAssemblyInfo or update each AssemblyInfo info with custom task. I'll give you example how to do it with CommonAssemblyInfo:

```
public class BuildScript : DefaultBuildScript
 {
        protected override void ConfigureBuildProperties(IBuildPropertiesContext context)
        {
            context.Properties.Set(BuildProps.CompanyName, "Company");

            context.Properties.Set(BuildProps.ProductId, "ProductId");
            context.Properties.Set(BuildProps.ProductName, "ProductName");
            context.Properties.Set(BuildProps.SolutionFileName, @"Solution.sln");
            context.Properties.Set(BuildProps.BuildConfiguration, "Release");
        }

        protected override void ConfigureTargets(ITaskContext context)
        {
            var loadSolution = context.CreateTarget("load.solution")
                .SetDescription("Load & analyze VS solution")
                .AddTask(x => x.LoadSolutionTask())
                .SetAsHidden();

            var fetchVersion = context.CreateTarget("fetch.version")
                .SetDescription("Fetch the build version")
                .Do(TargetFetchBuildVersion);

            var generateCommonAssInfo = context.CreateTarget("generate.commonAssInfo")
             .DependsOn(fetchVersion)
             .TaskExtensions()
                .GenerateCommonAssemblyInfo()
                .BackToTarget();

           var compile = context.CreateTarget("compile")
                .AddTask(x => x.CompileSolutionTask())
                .DependsOn(loadSolution, generateCommonAssInfo);
        }

        public static void TargetFetchBuildVersion(ITaskContext context)
        {
            var version = context.Tasks().FetchBuildVersionFromFileTask().Execute(context);
            string svnRevisionNumberString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SVN_REVISION");
            int svnRevisionNumber = 0;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(svnRevisionNumberString))
            {
                svnRevisionNumber = int.Parse(svnRevisionNumberString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            version = new Version(version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, svnRevisionNumber);
            context.Properties.Set(BuildProps.BuildVersion, version);
        }
}
```

Then you would run the script with flubu runner in cmd or jenkins as build step: `build.exe compile`

You have to include generated CommonAssemblyInfo into each project offcourse.