# .Net Core build with TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, .net-core, devops, teamcity-9.0

Has anyone got any experience of building .net core apps with TeamCity and Octopus? I know there are various guides on implementing this but they rely on having a project.json file which has been removed by Microsoft. Has anyone come up with any solution?

I'm currently using the dotnet-core-plugin suggested by TeamCity - but it appears to rely on the project.json file

Answer (score 1):

You could use FlubuCore. Flubu is A C# library that we wrote for building projects and executing deployment scripts using C# code.

Simple Example of how flubu is used in .net core

```
    protected override void ConfigureTargets(ITaskContext context)
    {
        var compile = context
            .CreateTarget("compile")
            .SetDescription("Compiles the VS solution")
            .AddCoreTask(x => x.ExecuteDotnetTask(StandardDotnetCommands.Restore).WithArguments("FlubuExample.sln"))
            .AddCoreTask(x => x.Build("FlubuExample.sln"));

       context
            .CreateTarget("Package")
            .CoreTaskExtensions()
            .DotnetPublish("FlubuExample.sln");

        var test = context.CreateTarget("test")
            .AddCoreTaskAsync(x => x.Test().WorkingFolder("FlubuExample.Tests"))
            .AddCoreTaskAsync(x => x.Test().WorkingFolder("FlubuExample.Tests2"));

        context.CreateTarget("Rebuild")
            .SetAsDefault()
            .DependsOn(compile, test);
    }
```

You can find more information about flubu and how to get started here:
[choice-for-build-tool-msbuild-nant-or-something-else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46776658/3118784)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the .NET CLI directly? I don't really know TeamCity or Octopus, but in Jenkins or AppVeyor I'm able to execute batch or PowerShell scripts. And I use this to run the .NET CLI commands directly. 
With this you are not dependent on any prebuilt, but out-dated add-ins.